# «Чернобыльский след» ― с большой или маленькой буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

С какой буквы следует писать "чернобыльский след"?

Answer (score 4):

Пишется строчными буквами: **чернобыльский след**.

Чернобыль - имя собственное, оно пишется с прописной буквы, но образованные от него прилагательные пишутся со строчной. Исключения составляют прилагательные, входящие в имя собственное, например "Чернобыльская атомная электростанция" — это имя собственное, название электростанции.